# Flutter errors when I run - Flutter build ios - though works fine in Debug

Tags: ios, flutter

Am trying to promote my first Flutter app to the appstore. But I get errors after running:

flutter build ios

Here are the errors:

2019-10-28 14:31:30.712760+0800 Clocky Sum[3010:726878] [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_data.cc(19)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
2019-10-28 14:31:30.712870+0800 Clocky Sum[3010:726878] [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm.cc(245)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
2019-10-28 14:31:30.712910+0800 Clocky Sum[3010:726878] [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(89)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
2019-10-28 14:31:30.713674+0800 Clocky Sum[3010:726878] [VERBOSE-3:shell.cc(215)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.

The annoying thing is that this works fine when I run it in debug mode again!!

Could anyone help with this please. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by opening xcode and going to: Product/Scheme/Edit scheme and changing the build configuration to Debug.